# Send a .txt with send_mail. Django

Tags: django, email

I want to send an email with django and I want the `body` of email to contains content from `.txt` file. I import from my templates. I went through the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/email/) but I didn't find how to do it.

Here is what I have in my views.py:

```
 send_mail('TEST', 'myfile.txt', 'admin@test.com', [test@test.com], fail_silently=False)
```

I tried to add `myfile.txt` to my template directory. But when I replace `'myfile.txt'` by `myfile.txt` in `send_mail()`, I off course got an error because `myfile.txt` is not a defined variable. Any idea on how I can accomplish that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want body of your email message to be the content of `myfile.txt` then (suppose `myfile.txt` is stored in `media > files > myfile.txt`):

```
from mysite.settings import MEDIA_ROOT
import os

file = open(MEDIA_ROOT + os.path.sep + 'files/myfile.txt', 'r')
content = file.read()
file.close()

# EmailMessage class version
mail = EmailMessage('subject', content, 'from@example.com', ['to@example.com'])
mail.send()

# send_mail version
send_mail('TEST', content, 'admin@test.com', [test@test.com], fail_silently=False)
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm trying to use: mail.attach_file('/files/myfile.txt')  But do I have to use absolute path? If not, what is the root directory?

Comment: Ok it works. Thank you. But I think my question wasn't clear enough. I want the body of my mail to be the .txt, I don't wan't it to be attached...

Comment: Sorry if I misunderstood your question. Please check my updated answer. The last part. Thanks

Comment: Welcome. I have again updated my answer and removed the attach file code as it was not required.

Answer (score 4):

What you need is `render_to_string`,

```
from django.template.loader import render_to_string
body = render_to_string('myfile.txt', foovars)
send_mail('TEST', body, 'admin@test.com', [test@test.com], fail_silently=False)
```

where `foovars` is a dict with the values that you need to render in the 'template' `myfile.txt` if proceed of course, else `{}`

be sure your `myfile.txt` lies on your template directory, that is all ;-)

Comment: This answer is way simple compared to the rest of them. And it worked great for me using django 1.6.